# Composer in Codeigniter prevents MY_ controllers from loading

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

After going through the agony of setting up composer in my Codeigniter project I put this:

```
  require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";
```

into my index.php file. After uploading everything to the server I got the error message that MY_Mainconroller (which is located in application/core) was not found in the main.php controller. For some weird reason the composer autoload destroys my CI.

I am using this method in the config.php for autoloading my customer controller extensions:

```
 function __autoload($class)
 {
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
       @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
 }
```

which worked perfectly fine before. Any pointers as to why this is happening are greatly appreciated.

I got as far as modifying the composer.json file and adding:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["application/core"]
}
```

Which was suggested on the CI Forum but that also did not resolve the issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have ONE `__autoload` function, and it is mutually exclusive with using `spl_autoload_*` functions, just as it is [documented in the PHP.net page](http://php.net/__autoload).

> **Tip** spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

From http://php.net/spl_autoload_register

> If your code has an existing __autoload() function then this function must be explicitly registered on the __autoload stack. This is because spl_autoload_register() will effectively replace the engine cache for the __autoload() function by either spl_autoload() or spl_autoload_call().

Now the solution is very easy: Use the autoloading feature of Composer. All you have to do is to add a new key "autoload" in your existing `composer.json` file. If your code respects PSR-0 standard, this might work:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MY\\" : "application/core/"
    }
}
```

This variant is least effort when developing, because new classes are immediately found.

Otherwise, you can use a classmap:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["application/core/"]
}
```

This will force you to recreate the autoloader every time you add a new class or rename it, because the old classmap will not know where to find it.

Have a look at the documentation of Composer. [Basics](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), [Details](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Note that I find your own autoload function a little bit odd. You are saying that for every class that is not beginning with "CI_" in it's name, you include a file. What about classes with "CI_" somewhere else in it's name? You are massively trying to autoload everything that does not start with "CI_" no matter if it can be found in your directory or not. The right thing would be to only load classes you know you are responsible for, like this:

```
if(strpos($class, 'MY_') === 0) // starts with "MY_"
{
   require_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
}
```

Note that the PSR-0 standard defines that every underscore in the classname is converted into a directory separator when not using namespaces. So if your classes are named "MY_foo", the relative path would be "MY/foo.php", i.e. "application/core/MY/foo.php". If you currently have "application/core/MY_foo.php", that wouldn't be compatible to PSR-0.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. However, only the spl_autoload_register part of it worked for me. I had previously tried the "classmap" approach which has no effect at all. The psr-0 method doesn't work for me for the reasons you suspected. And the autoloader function I used is copied from a Phil Sturgeon's blog. It's still a mystery to me why the "classmap" approach seems to work for everybody except me. Frustrating.

Comment: How is your constant `EXT` defined?

Comment: define('EXT', '.php'); which sits in the index.php file of Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is happening to you, but I seem to remember something similar when I first tried it. I now always put the:

```
$vendor_path = './vendor/autoload.php';

if (file_exists($vendor_path))
{
   require $vendor_path;
}
```

at the very top of my index.php file, before anything else, and it always runs smoothly

Comment: This didn't work for me. I read that you have to modify the composer.json file to include the autoload. I tried that too but it simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgetting to run 'composer dump-autoload' after modifying composer.json.

Here are the detailed steps. Please note I was using the exact same autoload script from Phil Sturgeon's blog and, just as with the original question, it broke when I added the Composer bit.

First, remove this from index.php (the Phil Sturgeon bit):

```
 function __autoload($class)
 {
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
       @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
 }
```

Then, add the following to index.php, right before the "LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE" bit. This is the composer autoload.

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD COMPOSER PACKAGES
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 */
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';
```

Add this to your composer.json. Now composer will be responsible of loading the files in your application/core folder.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["application/core/"]
}
```

Finally, and this is very important, dump autoload in composer.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It should work now.